# Frequency response

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-response

[image]

in 2.104 he put a condition that x(t) must be an exp to use this result ,but in 2.108 he did't even know what the value of x but use the result to get y

i know that he decompose x(t) to group of exp but still the amplitude for each exp isn't one

isn't it supposed to be
H(F)x(t)=lim summation{y(t)x(f)delta(f) ???

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question, could you edit the post and be a bit more clear? Also, please use Latex when writing mathematical formulas: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/editing-help